# SwiftUI Map MapPolyline not showing

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios17, swiftui-map

My intention is to display a SwiftUI.Map ([doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map)) with a line (that would represent a route) using `MapPolyline` ([see doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mappolyline)). Unfortunately, the line does not display on neither the simulator nor a physical device. Here's my code.

```
let deviceLocations = [
    // note: coordinates have be obfuscated for privacy reasons
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.1234, longitude: -83.1234),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 54.1235, longitude: -83.1235),
    ... // there a more points in my hard-coded array, but you get the idea...
]

var body: some View {
    Map(initialPosition: .userLocation(fallback: .automatic),
        bounds: nil,
        interactionModes: .all) {
        MapPolyline(coordinates: deviceLocations)
            .stroke(lineWidth: 2.0)
    }
        .mapControlVisibility(.hidden)
}
```

That's it. The simulator location is set to "Custom Location" with one of the coordinate from the list. That `View` is part of a view with other elements on it, but are not shown here (within a `ZStack`).

I don't know what I'm missing, and the documentation does not address this deeply enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Polyline still there. However, you can't see it because its content is empty. Try to fill with `Color` for example:

```swift
MapPolyline(coordinates: deviceLocations)
     .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 2.0)
```

Or create custom `ShapeStyle`:

```swift
struct CustomShapeStyle: ShapeStyle {
    func resolve(in environment: EnvironmentValues) -> some ShapeStyle {
        if environment.colorScheme == .light {
            return Color.blue.blendMode(.lighten)
        } else {
            return Color.blue.blendMode(.darken)
        }
    }
}
...
MapPolyline(coordinates: deviceLocations)
     .stroke(CustomShapeStyle(), lineWidth: 2.0)
```

Comment: hahaha I feel like a beginner... maybe I am! Thank you so much!
The `.blue` made it work; I'll play with the `CustomShapeStyle` later when I can. Again, thank you!

Comment: No big deal. Everyone does xD.